# Unable to change dropdown value in React child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components:

App component:

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedScale: "WholeTone"
    };
    this.handleScaleSelect = this.handleScaleSelect.bind(this);
  }

  handleScaleSelect = selectedScale => {
    console.log("ss: " + selectedScale);
    console.log(this.state);
    this.setState({ selectedScale: selectedScale });
    console.log("after ss:" + this.state.selectedScale);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Scales
          onSelectScale={this.handleScaleSelect}
          selected={this.state.selectedScale}
        ></Scales>
    )
  }
}
```

Scales component:

```js
class Scales extends Component {
  state = {
    options: []
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // this.getScales();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={() => this.props.onSelectScale(this.getSelectedScale())}>
        <select id="scaleSelectId"></select>
        <input type="submit" value="render scale" />
      </form>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    function addOptions() {
      var select = document.getElementById("scaleSelectId");
      JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).map(scale => {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = scale;
        select.add(option);
      });
      select.value = this.props.selected;
    }
    xhr.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_scales");
    xhr.onload = addOptions.bind(this);
    xhr.send();
  }
}
```

I want to change dropdown value, press form's submit button and pass that value to the parent element so it is used further. I wonder what am I doing wrong. I did some logging in `handleScaleSelect` to see what's going on, and weirdly - the `selectedScale` variable is equal to the submitted value, but the state of component is not altered.

Comment: Does it throw any error?

Comment: What values should the select dropdown have in it?

Comment: @jeninja values are strings, names of musical scales. And the value of dropdown should be changed to one the user chooses

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. In React we usually add values to the DOM using `{arr.map(v => <div>value</div>)}`. So I added that.

I also created two functions inside the `Scales.js` file. `handleSelect()` and `submitForm()`. These functions take the event emitted by the `<select />` and `<form />` attributes respectively. I binded these functions in our constructor at the top.

Lastly, I moved `componentDidMount()` inside the React.Component.

NOTE: Since I do not have access to the API you are calling, I had to create my own array of test values which was `var optionsArr = [1,2,3,4,5];`.

App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import Scales from './Scales';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedScale: 'WholeTone'
    };
    this.handleScaleSelect = this.handleScaleSelect.bind(this);
  }

  handleScaleSelect = selectedScale => {
    this.setState({ selectedScale: selectedScale });
    this.postXML();
  };

  postXML() {
    // your XMLR code here
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>App.js Selected Scale: {this.state.selectedScale}</h1>
        <Scales onSelectScale={this.handleScaleSelect} selectedScale={this.state.selectedScale}></Scales>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Scales.js

```js
import React from 'react';

class Scales extends React.Component {
  state = {
    options: [],
    selectedOption: 'default'
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
    this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ selectedOption: this.props.selectedScale });
    this.getScales();
  }

  getScales() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    function addOptions() {
      var optionsArr = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      this.setState({ options: optionsArr });
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_scales');
    xhr.onload = addOptions.bind(this);
    xhr.send();
  }

  handleSelect(event) {
    this.setState({ selectedOption: event.target.value });
  }

  submitForm(event) {
    if (event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // stops page from refreshing when click form button
    }
    this.props.onSelectScale(this.state.selectedOption);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
        <h1>Scale.js Selected Scale: {this.state.selectedOption}</h1>
        <select id="scaleSelectId" value={this.selectedOption} onChange={this.handleSelect}>
          {this.state.options.map((value, index) => {
            return (
              <option key={index} value={value}>
                {value}
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="render scale" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Scales;
```

Comment: this seems to work, but as I said I need to process the selected value further. Originally I have also a componentDidMount function in the App component that makes an XHR request based on selected value, and without the page refreshing componentDidMount won't fire...

Comment: ok, I added the XHR request in `Scales.js` into its own function, we can call whenever we want. In this case I called it in `componentDidMount`, we can do the same thing in App.js. Just put XHR into its own function and then call it in `handleScaleSelect()`.